# Is it ever revealed what drove Fistandantilus to immortality?

Tags: dragonlance

Scant details are known about the early life of the Archmage Fistandantilus, the Dark One. One of the few details, and also what had become his singularly driving obsession was that he was able to keep himself alive through magic when he was young.

Later after he past his Trial and became a Red Robe, he stayed a follower of neutrality until he realized that he would not live forever. He then approached Gilean about extending his life, but the god responded that the mage should accept his humanity.

This drove Fistandantilus to becoming a Black Robe and crystallized his quest for immortality.

Was it ever explained why he was was so focused on living forever; fear, power, anything specific?

Comment: Being immortal isn't its own reward?

Comment: I’m not quite sold on how rewarding a never ending incorporealized existence might be.

Comment: Ask me in nine hundred years time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immortality is its own reward, of course:

> "You cannot know, young man, the horrors of growing old. how well I
> remember my first life and how well I remember the terrible feeling of
> anger and frustration I felt when I realized that I -- the most
> powerful magic-user who had ever lived -- was destined to be trapped
> in a weak and wretched body that was being consumed by age! [...] But
> all this power, all this vast knowledge would be wasted -- turned to
> dust! Devoured by worms!"
> (*Annotated Legends*, pp. 464-465)

Furthermore, Fistandantilus wanted to amass magical power and ascend to godhood. The desires to live forever and "be like gods" are the original Biblical temptation (*Annotated Legends*, p. 396, margin note, and p. 465, margin note).

A single human lifetime is not enough for this; he'd lived for 2000 (*Heroes of Defiance*, p. 63) to 2500 years (*Towers of High Sorcery*, p. 89; this same page says Fistandantilus was young when he joined the Black Robes, contradicting *Legends*) when he died in the attempt to enter the Abyss and kill Takhisis.

Fistandantilus going for Takhisis is Rule 2 of Dragonlance: evil feeds upon itself (*Annotated Legends*, p. 373, margin note).

It is interesting to note that aspiring for immortality and godhood (and thus recapitulating the sin of Adam and Eve) is not a particularly evil act, especially compared to Raistlin recapitulating the sin of Cain and nearly murdering his brother in a fit of jealous rage.

> I’m not quite sold on how rewarding a never ending incorporealized existence might be.

He didn't plan to die and become a ghost; in fact he might have meticulously planned his continuing *corporeal* existence, as both of his deaths were brought about by the influence of Chaos (Gnimsh's device in AC 39 and Raistlin traveling with Tasslehoff to PC 1).